# Multiple check box not working when it's value same vuejs

Tags: checkbox, vuejs2

When I check Apple it's all check Pineapple. When I unchecked Pineapple it's also unchecked Apple.
both Tag id different. How can I check only one Apple instead of Pineapple?

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  },
  computed: {
    computedNames() {
      let names = this.checkedNames;
      return names.toString();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input type="checkbox" id="50" value="50" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="Apple">Apple</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="51" value="51" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="Banana">Banana</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="52" value="50" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="Pineapple">Pineapple</label>
  <br>
  <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
  <span>Computed names (reversed order): {{ computedNames }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Both your first and last checkboxes have the same `value`. Since Vue is data-driven, this results in both checkboxes being linked

Comment: But I want only add apple, not pineapple. I know its the same price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue is data-driven. Since both your *Apple* and *Pineapple* checkboxes have the same `value`, Vue considers them to be the same.

It sounds like you want to use separate objects entirely so try this

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: () => ({
    options: [{
      id: 50,
      label: "Apple",
      price: 50
    }, {
      id: 51,
      label: "Banana",
      price: 51
    }, {
      id: 52,
      label: "Pineapple",
      price: 50
    }],
    selections: []
  }),
  computed: {
    computedNames: ({ selections }) =>
      selections.map(({ label }) => label).join(", ")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <template v-for="fruit in options">
    <input
      :key="fruit.id"
      type="checkbox" 
      :value="fruit" 
      v-model="selections" 
      :id="`fruit_${fruit.id}`"
    >
    <label :for="`fruit_${fruit.id}`">{{ fruit.label }}</label>
  </template>
  <br>
  <span>Computed names: {{ computedNames }}</span>
  <pre>Selections: {{ selections }}</pre>
</div>
```